# Binance Smart Chain RPC Rate Limit

Tags: web3js, json-rpc, web3-providers, bsc, binance

In the [BSC documentation](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html#rate-limit), it says that we can make 10K/5mins RPC requests to their servers. Do you guys know if it's 10K per app or user?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since these are public endpoints, they are probably monitoring your usage by your IP address. So you can only do 10K requests/5min from your IP. It doesn't matter if you have more applications or accounts (since you don't need an account to use these endpoints anyway)

If you're looking for a higher rate limit BSC node, you should check out my company [moralis.io](https://moralis.io). You can get a free BSC node with 3600 reqs/1 min.

For transparency, there are also other free node providers that will give you BSC nodes, like [getblock.io](https://getblock.io) or [quicknode.com](https://www.quicknode.com/), but their free tiers are not as generous as moralis. For example, getblock.io will give you 40K reqs/day, while moralis with it's 3600 RPS will give you 5 million reqs/day for free.

Comment: Do we need to create account and use some API key?

Comment: Yes, you need a free account to get that high of a rate limit. We can't have a public endpoint that has such generous limits, since it would be abused. But an account is free and takes 30s to create.

Comment: Looks good, do you also have ETH / Polygon free nodes with the same limit?